# Center Text in a Button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got the following `View`:

```
HStack {
  ...
  VStack {
    ...
    Button(action: model.signIn) {
      HStack {
        Text("Sign In")
        Spacer()
      }
    }.relativeHeight(2).background(Color.green).cornerRadius(5)
  }
  ...
}
```

This allows me to create the following UI:

[image]

The `Spacer` inside the `HStack` and `Button` was a nice hack that made the button extend to the width of its parent. However, the text is still sitting at the leading position.

Anyone know of a way to centre the text inside the button?

Comment: Add a spacer before the text as well as after. Or just remove the spacer that you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in two ways,

1. Remove the `Spacer` after the text - this will shrink the button to
   match txt size.
2. Add a `Spacer` before text. like

Code:

```
HStack {
  ...
  VStack {
    ...
    Button(action: model.signIn) {
      HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Sign In")
        Spacer()
      }
    }.relativeHeight(2).background(Color.green).cornerRadius(5)
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
HStack {
  ...
  VStack {
    ...
    Button("Sign In") {
        model.signIn()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center).padding()
    .background(Color.green).cornerRadius(5)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I disagree. these codes are so easy, an explanation would just duplicate it. After all code is the lingua franca.